# "angular is not defined" error while executing Protractor test on angular application stored in Liferay

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, protractor, e2e-testing

i'm running on a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual-host and i'm trying to create some E2E tests with PROTRACTOR for and Application hosted in "Liferay".

For the login section (that doesn't require angular) the test with protractor are Ok, the page logins and navigates correctly, but when i try to open a "drop-down" menu on the angularjs based app with the following code:

```
<select class = "form-control menu-select ng-pristine ng-valid"
ng-model = "topTitlesData.topFiveDateRange"
name = "topFiveDateRange"
ng-options = "range.name for range in        topTitlesData.topFiveDateRangeValues"
ng-change = "" > < option value = "0" > Last day < /option><option value="1">Last 5 days</option > < option value = "2" > Last 7 days < /option><option value="3">Last 30 days</option > < option value = "4" > last 90 days < /option></select>
```

i got this error log:

UnknownError: unknown error: angular is not defined

```js
This is the test script on js:


describe('pages with login', function() {
  it('should log in with a non-Angular page and select and option', funcion() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('***************');
    element(by.id('_58_login')).clear();
    element(by.id('_58_login')).sendKeys('*******');
    expect(element(by.id('_58_login')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('*****');
    element(by.id('_58_password')).sendKeys('*****', protractor.Key.ENTER);
    browser.get('***************');
    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    var selects = element.all(by.model('topTitlesData.topFiveDateRange'));
    expect(selects.count()).toEqual(5);
  });
});
```

i'm wondering, what am i missing ?

i have nodejs, protractor, webadmin-manager,jdk7.* installed and updated

Comment: are the spaces in `ng - model`, `ng - options`, and `ng - change` typos?

Comment: yes, those are typos. i'll correct them now..

Comment: but i'm still having the same issue, those typos were created when i opened the ticket

Comment: `UnknownError: unknown error: angular is not defined` almost always occurs when angular doesn't initialize because it's missing a dependency somewhere.  Can you post more of the HTML page where this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, the issue was that the tests didn't wait till angular in loaded to the page... so i setup a localhost with the application with "Grunt", "Yeoman" and Ruby + "ruby-compass" gem and avoided liferay. I also setup

```js
allScriptsTimeout: 5000000,
```

in the config.js file and now the tests is running okay.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely that your tests are running before the browser page is completely loaded. The `angular` global variable has not been created yet. You can ensure that all has been loaded before tests start by putting the following line in your `protractor.conf.js` file's `onPrepare` method:

```
browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
```

This will navigate to the page before any tests start and ensure that all is loaded.

Comment: I have found the same error, when I used Selenium Webdriver test. Thanks for explanation. In my case, I've just added a *Thread.sleep(200);* before script used for detecting if angular is loaded, and all works fine.