# Need to get the text box value which not exposed in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my page I have a text box which displaying user name ("XXXX") from angular object value(user.userName). Can anyone help me how I can able to retrieve the value using Protractor.

HTML:

```
<label _ngcontent-c11="">User Name</label>
<input _ngcontent-c11="" type="text">
```

I have tried with below script:

```
var ele = element(by.xpath("//*[label='User Name']/input"));
ele.evaluate('user').then(function(value) { console.log(value); });
```

But it throws as error:

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: angular is not defined
```

Comment: You didn't add the reference for angular. Check all your references and check if angular is loading or not in networks tab.

Comment: All expected angular service loaded in the page. How can I add the angular reference based on the above HTML.

Comment: Can you show your index file?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28421585/7040254